# Interoperability of types in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, language-interoperability

A very simple question: are there any guarantees that a C `int` is the same thing as a C++ `int`, on the same system?

It goes without saying that this is, of course, a purely theoretical question.

The C and C++ standards use the same language to define the fundamental types. But whereas Fortran 2003 makes it clear that

```
use ISO_C_BINDING
integer(kind=c_int) :: i
```

declares an integer type which is compatible with the `int` type on a "companion C processor", I can't find any such assertion in the C++ stardard. It seems very odd that Fortran would provide stronger C interoperability guarantees than C++!

The closest I can find is section 7.5 [dcl.link], paragraph 3 of the C++11 standard, which states that

> Every implementation shall provide for linkage to functions written in the C programming language

But this little sentence doesn't (to me) seem strong enough to guarantee compatibility of fundamental types.

Is there some other language in the C++ standard that I've overlooked which guarantees this, or is it just so obviously taken for granted that no-one has bothered to state it explicitly?

**EDIT**: David Schwartz in the comments points out that I was imprecise when I said "the same system". I really meant the same "platform", i.e. hardware, OS, system libraries etc. It's really an ABI issue of course. In the quoted passage the C++ standard seems to want to indicate that you can call C functions with `extern "C"`, but I'm not sure if it provides enough other guarantees?

Comment: I'd extend *on the same system* to *on the same system with the same compiler and compiler settings*. Otherwise the answer will definitely be no (you can compile a i386 binary with 32-bit int on a 64-bit system)

Comment: What does "the same system" mean? Same hardware? Same OS? Same compiler suite? Same system libraries?

Comment: Perhaps 3.9.1p3 `The signed and unsigned integer
types shall satisfy the constraints given in the C standard, section 5.2.4.2.1.` ?

Comment: @JesseGood That sentence doesn't appear in the C++11 draft I have (n3337) -- I guess I need to find a newer one. That seems to cover it I think -- but leaves open the question of floating point types, `bool`/`_Bool` and standard-layout structs...

Comment: @TristanBrindle: That part was added due to [defect report 483](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3383.html). You are right about other fundamental types. I don't think the C standard makes any requirements for floating point types though.

Comment: @JesseGood: 5.2.4.2.1 is phrased in terms of minimum ranges per "shall be equal ***or greater*** in magnitude"... a C++ compiler could satisfy those requirements having used a wider or narrower `int` than a specific C compiler (with specific command line args etc.).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good point. I really meant the same "platform", i.e. hardware, OS, system libraries etc. It's really an ABI issue of course, and C++ seems to want to indicate that `extern "C"` should let you call C functions -- but I'm not sure if it actually does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

There are widely used conforming compilers on x64 amd compatible cpus that treat `long`as 32 bit and others as 64 bit by default.  So this is not even the case for two C++ compilers on the same system, let alone a C++ and C compiler.

Within one compiler, that is up to the compiler vendor if they are compatible.  They usually (always) are.  "one compiler" is a bit of a misnomer here: the C snd C++ compilers are different compilers, even if in the same binary by the same vendor, in a sense.

Comment: The answer is correct. The C and C++ standards use similar language, and clearly make no guarantees that any integers are any particular size. I do not believe the Fortran compiler can make good on its promise either, for similar reasons.